# optimal hamiltonian cycle in the Nearest Neighbor algorithm for the Traveling Salesman Problem

Tags: hamiltonian-circuit

how to prove that in the Nearest Neighbor algorithm for the Traveling Salesman Problem with one modification, if it finds a hamiltonian cycle, it's the optimal cycle. the modification is if the shortest path it could choose is an edge to a node already visited, the algorithm stops.

Comment: What is "the Nearest Neighbor algorithm for the Traveling Salesman Problem"?  I suggest you provide pseudocode for the algorithm you have in mind, including the modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I want to make sure I understand you correctly. You are considering the following algorithm, which I will call $\mathscr{A}$.

1. Given: a set $V$ of $n$ nodes/points and a metric $d:V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$
2. Pick $v_1 \in V$ arbitrarily
3. For $i=1,2,\ldots, n-1$:

   3.1. Find $u^* = \arg\min_{u \in V\setminus\{v_i\}} d(u, v_i)$

   3.2. If $u^* = v_j$ for any $j \in \{1,\ldots,i-1\}$ return FAIL.

   3.3. Otherwise set $v_{i+1} = u^*$
4. If $d(v_1, v_n) > \min_{u \in V} d(u, v_n)$ return FAIL.
5. Otherwise return the Hamiltonian cycle $(v_1, \ldots, v_n, v_1)$.

[I am a little unsure if this is exactly the algorithm you are proposing, since normally in the nearest neighbour algorithm there is no check that $v_1$ is the nearest neighbour of $v_n$. However, without this the statement you want to prove is false. If I am wrong about the algorithm please correct me.]
You then want to prove that if $\mathscr{A}$ returns a Hamiltonian cycle, then it returns the optimal Hamiltonian cycle.
I feel like there should be a proof that follows the strategy used for proving the correctness of many greedy algorithms: look at an optimal solution, suppose it is different from the greedy solution, arrive at a contradiction. However, I admittedly keep hitting roadblocks.